# Could you recommend some jQuery/Javascript plugins that handles picture upload/delete/modify?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a plugin of this kind.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/create-a-photo-admin-site-using-php-and-jquery/

It is not only Javascript I mean you need more than that but his will get you going!

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/what-is-it/) - uses Flash for progress tracking, and obviously, you have to handle the upload on the server side.